# Properties in a relationship in neo4j referencing another entity

Tags: neo4j

I am new to Neo4j and I am trying to convert a relational model to a graph model. In this model, I have two labels X and Y which there is a relationship between them. This relationship has property P. The problem is that this P should get its values from an external table (list of possible values for P). How should I relate this property values to be obtained from this external table.

Comment: Can you describe a bit more about the tables and properties in your relational model, and what data has already been converted into your graphical model? Your description of "a list of possible values for P" doesn't really give us anything to work with, we'll need to know what properties exist in the table, and how they relate to your nodes with labels X and Y.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In my relational model, I have a table called unit which has two columns, ID and UnitName (cm, km, year, day, etc). There is also a joint table that connect two tables X and Y which have a many to many relationship together. This joint table itself has a relationship with the unit table (So this joint table has just three columns, primary key of X, primary key of Y and also primary key of Unit table). When we want to convert a relational model to a graph model we have to transform (promote) joint records of our join table to relationship. continue in next msg ...

Comment: So in this case, unitID (primary key of unit table) should be converted to a property of the relation between X and Y table. So my question is how can I relate this property (unitID) to my Unit table. This is the my relational model and my graph model: https://postimg.org/image/s6g4y2iud/    In case that this link does not work try this one: http://tinypic.com/r/wtdmqp/9         thanks a lot

Comment: Another point is that the unit table also has relations with other tables than this joint table too.

Comment: No suggestion David?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I'm completely following, but at the most basic level, if you already have x and y nodes modeled and populated (with unique constraints on the primary keys), and if you have a join table with x and y primary keys and a value that should be on the relationship, then it's a matter of reading in the import file of the join table, matching to the corresponding x and y nodes via the primary keys, then merging the appropriate relationship between them, adding any additional properties on the relationship as needed.

However, it's always a good idea to check if this is the best way to model what you want in a graph db. So far you've only been describing tables and how they relate, but getting a better description of the big picture of what this data represents and logically how it relates to each other might provide insights for modeling the data in a way that makes more sense for a graph db. Could you provide in your description a more verbal description of what exactly you're trying to model, how it relates to each other, and the kind of questions you want to ask of your data?